# how to find the Person based on the Person‘ name

Tags: java

I have an Person array ， and I want to find the specific Person based on its name. 
How could I do that?

```
// Person
public class Person {
    String name;
    private Person [] adjacent;
    public int adjacentCount;

    public Person(String n){
        this.name=n;
    }

    public void addAdjacent(Person x){
        if(adjacentCount<30){
            this.adjacent[adjacentCount]=x;
            adjacentCount++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("No more adjacent can be added");
        }
}
    public Person[] getAdjacent(){
        return adjacent;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

Now we need to add person to a graph，and make the method addFriendship, and now I am wondering how to know the person from graph if we only know its name

```
public void addFriendship(String name1, String name2){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you assume you can get to every other Person from one root (given it's a assignment).  The first problem you have is you should expect lots of circular dependencies. For example is A is a friend of B, B is likely to be friend of A.  Also if A is a friend of C, it is fairly likely that C is a friend of B.  What you need a way of traversing the Graph visiting each node only once.

The standard solution for doing this is to use an IdentityHashMap (which you have said you can't use) but you can implement your own (a bit painful but doable)  This keeps track of each node you have seen, to avoid going round and round in loops.

---

I would maintain a `Map<String, Person>` so you can look up a Person by name.

The problem with a graph like this is you need cannot assume every person is connected to every other person. i.e. not everyone is reachable. Also knowing when to stop is tricky.

BTW I suggest you look at neo4j which is a very cool database from graph data.

Comment: the problem is that this assignment is not allowed to use any libraries, including java.util.*

Comment: well then you will need to traverse the graph yourself. maybe [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal) will get you started.

Comment: @user3147438 It's always a suspect requirement because `java.lang.String` is in the same library. The only solutions I can think of use the `java.util` in some form.

Comment: @user3147438 well put that _into the question_. We're not psychic.

Comment: @user3147438 I have added to my answer.